# Why does the init() method of a servlet run in a different thread?

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, tomcat, servlets

This is an excerpt from the book "Head First Servlets and JSP". What I don't understand is why the `init()` method alone runs in thread `A`, and the `service()` methods that come after run in a different thread, `B`.

Does this mean every request from the browser to the servlet gets two threads? Or is  `init()` common for all servlet instances that a container might create? That would be wrong because it is not a static method?

[image]

Comment: `init()` is run only once during servlet initialization and runs in a thread that starts the application. On the other hand, `service()` is called for each request on a random container thread, usually taken from a thread pool.

Comment: As it’s written in the description: init is run on startup. It’s not run for each request. This is kind of misleading since not every request gets a different thread but the idea is it’s not single-threaded.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The servlet is initialized just once by `init()`, but for every new request a new thread is created or allocated from a pool to invoke that *servlet* instance on the appropriate method.

---

The `HttpRequest` and `HttpResponse` objects will be new for each new request, and the **thread**, but ***not the servlet instance***.

Comment: This answers the question, so the one servlet instance will be destroyed only when server is shutdown or it will be destroyed any of time (like maybe if it was idle and no request was served for some time)

Comment: All the Servlet instances are destroyed when server is shutting down or on application disposal.

Comment: Remember: *You can't destroy the Servlet manually and Servlet is just like worker not for data container.*

Answer (score 1):

This description applies to single servlet instance. Intuitively you can think of it as processing requests in other threads not to block the main thread. If the request is time-costly, there is no point in freezing the application to serve it, so every request leads to fork.